# Issues on blocking magento website

Tags: magento2, security, magento-community, security-scan-tool

Is there any way where a magento website is enabled and opens even if teh internal IT firewall blocks it.

Also no one blocked my website in the office. Still i am not able to open it in the office network, whereas many other websites are opening. Any solution?

Comment: Are you able o ping to your domain/ip address of your site?

Comment: if your firewall blocks some ip, you will have some issues, as your ip address can be different.